# Dropdown in ribbon is not visible - TemplateAlias problem?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom-actions

I have the following code, the button is shown but the dropdownlist is not visible.  I think the problem is with templatealias, but I dont understand very well how this thing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your XML - you've used the group size "LargeLarge" from the Flexible2 template that dropdown isn't capable to support:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: The display mode with name: Large is
>   not valid for this control with id:
>   SP.WikiActions.FolderDropdown

I've changed the MaxSize to MediumMedium (if you check the Flexible2 template in CMDUI.xml - it contains three rows of the small controls) and all have rendered correctly:

```
<MaxSize Id="SP.WikiActions.MaxSize"
                   Sequence="11"
                   GroupId="SP.WikiActions"
                   Size="MediumMedium" />
```

So you need to use as the scaling to your dropdown group any scaling that contains modes supported by dropdown.

BTW [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx)'s a recomendation for using templates in your custom groups:

> When defining custom groups in ribbon customization Features,
>   Microsoft recommends that developers create their own group template
>   instead of using one of the provided group templates. The reason for
>   this is that SharePoint does not load the entire ribbon for every page
>   request; only the parts of the ribbon that are needed for the current
>   context are loaded. This includes the group templates. Therefore, if
>   developers rely on the built-in group templates, there is a chance the
>   template will not be loaded for the current page and their ribbon
>   customizations will not appear.

**UPDATE**:
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407290.aspx)'s the walkthrough  that includes a group template creation. I'm planning to cover this things in deep details myself but need some time to do it. :)

Comment: I agree with that, I had already read that, but I cant find any good documentation in how to create group templates, it looks complicated, any link you can share about this special topic.

Comment: See the update. And the main point of my answer was a resolution of the problem described - does it helps you? :)

Comment: I've added what you need to modify.

Comment: thanks for your help, it looks you have a lot of experience in this topic, could you please read this one also? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30813/dropdown-list-in-ribbon-not-being-populated